# Meaning of 莫逮 in Classical texts?

Tags: translation, usage, classical-chinese

Some examples of 莫逮 found in Classical texts:

> 三國志．卷二十一．魏書．王粲傳：「昔伯牙絕絃於鍾期，仲尼覆醢于子路，痛知音之難遇，傷門人之**莫逮**也。」

> 《南齐书·周盘龙传》
> 形甚羸訥, 而臨軍勇果, 諸將莫逮。

> 《宋史•朱弁传》:“叹马角之未生,魂销雪窖;攀龙髯而莫逮,泪洒冰天。”

> 《荀子·尧问》
> 楚莊王 謀事而當羣臣莫逮, 退朝而有憂色。

I'm assuming here **莫** is of the whole 没、不，勿 nature.

**逮** as a classical text can only be dài (or dì) but definitely not dǎi.

If we go with dài we have:

**Gu Hanyu Da Cidian**

> ①及;到。
>
> ②逮捕。

**Students Dictionary of Classical and Medieval Chinese**

> 1 come to, reach a point in place or time; extend to, up to.
>
> a measure up (to standard), be equally matched; catch up to
>
> b when, by the time of; until; keep on till.
>
> 2 nab, seize; apprehend, arrest; attain, acquire, obtain.
>
> a seize the moment for, catch the chance of; take advantage of.

If we go with the (very unlikely) pronunciation of dì then it would mean something like

**Gu Hanyu Da Cidian**

> 娴雅貌。

莫 has a ton of other meanings.

逮 has other meanings, not mentioned here, aswell.

What's the best way to interpret 莫逮 in these classical texts?

What's the best translation?

Comment: 莫=不, 逮=及, so 莫逮=不及 (cannot reach that level). I'm not kidding XD

Comment: @Stan why don't you write up an answer...?

Comment: Because I don't have a dictionary for classical texts at hand, I'm not sure if it has other meanings, besides, I don't quite like writing single-line answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

昔伯牙絕絃於鍾期，仲尼覆醢于子路，痛知音之難遇，傷門人之莫逮也。 Means a person lost his(her) bosom friend, he (she) is so sad, and not one can acquaintance him(her) like the past friend.So the 莫逮 here is can not be comparable to something(someone), 莫 means can not, 逮 means can be comparable to something(someone).